# Understanding code with use of the malloc() function and pointers

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to document some code to improve my knowledge of pointers and general ANSI C ability.

```
 ...
 int static_store = 30;
 const char * pcg = "String Literal";
 int main()
 {
     int auto_store = 40;
     char auto_string[] = "Auto char Array";
     int * pi;
     char * pcl;
     pi = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
     *pi = 35;
     pcl = (char *) malloc(strlen("Dynamic String") + 1);
     strcpy(pcl, "Dynamic String");
 ...
```

From first looks, two pointers are initialised, pi and pcl, of type int and char respectively.

But the lines after are confusing to me and I don't understand what is happening. I can see that malloc is being called to allocate memory the size of int (40). Is it assigning memory to the variables pi and pcl?

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: " the size of int (40)" ??

Comment: Title is missleading. Might had said "Trying to understand" rather than "Documenting". `pi` initialization and use is not conventional. For some reason they are allocating the space for an int in the memory heap instead of the stack (if they defined pi as a simple int). Then they allocate just the space for an string (the content plus the \0 terminator).

Comment: So basically you are asking "what is the purpose of the malloc function". Your C book should be able to answer that question.

Comment: To set terms right: `malloc` does not assign anything. That is done by the _assignment-operator_ `=`. `malloc` also does not return "memory", but the address of an allocated memory block (on successful allocation). And a pointer is the suitable container for an address. **Think about it**. Niote: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. C is **not** C++! Warning: Always check the result of system functions which might fail. `malloc` might return a _null pointer_!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it assigning memory to the variables pi and pcl?

Yes `malloc` is **allocating** memory to these pointers.

`pi` is allocated memory equal to `sizeof(int)`(that may vary) and `pcl` has be allocated memory equal to `length of string plus 1`(plus 1 for `null character`).

> From first looks, two pointers are initialised, pi and pcl, of type int and char respectively

They are **declared** not initialized.

Note- [Please don't cast return of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

2 pointers are **delcared** (`pi` and `pcl`).  At declaration they are **not** intialized.
`pi` is then pointed to a block of heap allocated memory that can hold 1 int (the size of this is platform dependant but it would usually be 4 bytes) allocated with the fucntion `maloc`.  Somewhere this memory will have to be explicitely freed with the funtion `free` - failing to do so will be a memory leak.
The int value 35 is then stored at that memory location.  `*pi` can be read as "what the pointer pi points to" it is effectively the same as `pi[0]`.
`pcl` is then pointed to a block of heap allocated memory that is large enough to hold 14 char plus a '\0' char (i.e 15 bytes) using the function `malloc` (as above at some point this memory must be freed).
The 15 characters "Dynamic String\0" is then put in that memory using the function `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

The line:
`pi = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int))`
Actually allocate memory for one int variable. The line afterwards, puts the value 35 into that variable.

The line: 
`pcl = (char *) malloc(strlen("Dynamic String") + 1)`
Creates a dynamically allocated char array (which is equivalent to a string). The size of that array is of the length of the string ("Dynamic String") plus one. The next line copies the string: "Dynamic String" into the allocated array. The plus one is needed because each string in `c` ends with the char `'\0'` which is a sign for the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `malloc` function reserves a block of memory in the *heap* (the dynamic memory pool), and returns a pointer to the first element of that block of memory.  That memory is reserved until you call `free`, or the program exits.

In the call

```
pi = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

`malloc` reserves a block of memory large enough to store a single `int` value, and the pointer to that memory block is assigned to `pi`.  You do not need to cast the result of `malloc`<sup>1</sup>, and it's actually considered bad practice<sup>2</sup>.  A better way to write that would be

```
pi = malloc( sizeof *pi );
```

The expression `*pi` has type `int`, so `sizeof *pi` is equivalent to `sizeof (int)`<sup>3</sup>.  The advantage of using `sizeof *pi` over `sizeof (int)` (as well as dropping the cast) is that if you ever change the type of `pi` (from `int *` to `long *`, for example), you won't have to change anything in the `malloc` call; it will always allocate the right amount of memory regardless of the type of `pi`.  It's one less maintenance headache to worry about.

Similarly, the call

```
pcl = (char *) malloc(strlen("Dynamic String") + 1);
```

reserves enough memory to hold the contents of `"Dynamic String"` (the +1 is necessary for the string terminator) and assigns the pointer to that memory to `pcl`.  Again, this would be better written as

```
pcl = malloc( strlen("Dynamic String") + 1 ); // no cast
```

`sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, so you don't need an explicit `sizeof *pcl` in the call above; however, if you ever decide to change the type of `pcl` from `char *` to `wchar_t *`, it would be good to have it in place, although you'd still have to change the string literal and change how you compute the length, so it's not maintenance-free.

The general form a `malloc` call is

```
T *p = malloc( num_elements * sizeof *p ); // where num_elements > 1
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = malloc( num_elements * sizeof *p );
```

There is a similar function named `calloc` that will zero out the allocated memory block:

```
T *p = calloc( num_elements, sizeof *p );
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = calloc( num_elements, sizeof *p );
```

---

<sup>1. In C, anyway; C++ *does* require the cast, since C++ does not allow implicit conversions between `void *` and other pointer types.  But you shouldn't be using `malloc` in C++ code, anyway. 


So why do people still cast the result of `malloc` in C?  It's largely a holdover from pre-ANSI days (more than a quarter of a century ago), when `malloc` returned `char *`, which cannot be assigned to a different pointer type without a cast.  The 1989 standard introduced the `void *` type, which is essentially a "generic" pointer that can be assigned to other pointer types without an explicit cast.


2.  Under the C89 standard, if the compiler sees a function call without having seen a declaration for that function, it will assume that the function returns `int`.  Thus, if you forget to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise don't have a declaration for `malloc` in scope, the compiler will assume it returns an `int` value and generate the machine code for the call accordingly.  However, `int` and pointer types aren't *compatible*, and normally the compiler will issue diagnostic if you try to assign one to the other.  By using the cast, however, you supress that diagnostic, and you may run into runtime problems later on.


The 1999 standard did away with implicit `int` typing for functions, so that's not really a problem anymore, but the cast is still unnecessary and leads to maintenance problems.  


3.  `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function; parentheses are only required if the operand is a type name like `int` or `double` or `struct blah`.</sup>